# Sumatoria en ciclo for

Tags: python, bucles

Tengo que programar una suma de Reimann. Tenía la idea de hacerla con un ciclo `for` que fuera calculando los valores de las areas de los rectangulos para guardarlo en una variable.
Pero no sé cómo podría sumar los resultados obtenidos del ciclo `for`. El código es en Python

```
import math
import numpy as np

print("- Calculadora de la suma de Reimann para la función seno -")
print("")
print("Por favor, especifique los siguientes parametros para hacer sus 
cálculos: ")
print("")
a=float(input("1.- El punto a de su intervalo: "))
b=float(input("2.- El punto b de su intervalo: "))
n=float(input("3.- El número n de rectángulos con el cual desea hacer 
    su cálculo: "))

dn=(b-a)/n

def f(x):
    y=np.sin(x)
    return (y)

def RiemannINF( a, b, f, dn):
    for i in range ( a, b, dn):
        ap=...
```

Es lo que llevo de código.
No estoy muy seguro de cómo poder plantear la suma con ciclos `for` y me vendría bien una mano.

Comment: Y donde esta lo que has intentado? Sin ver el código es difícil ayudar

Comment: Ejemplo suma = suma + valor (sumas a la variable un valor y reemplazas el valor anterior de la variable por el nuevo). En python, esto se simplifica a suma += valor

Comment: Por cierto, [Te podrían votar negativamente porque pedir ayuda urgente es descortés y hasta grosero](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4152). Por que tu tiempo importa más que el de los otros (los que preguntan y responden)?

Comment: Muestranos el ciclo `for` para decirte donde. Mejor muestra un código completo.

Comment: Eso es lo que llevo de codigo, no estoy seguro de como plantear bien la suma, si pudieran apoyarme estaría muy agradecido

Answer (score 2):

Deberías aprender a usar la función nativa de Python [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/functions.html#sum).
La función sumará todos los valores dentro de un iterable.
En tu caso le podemos pasar una comprensión de los valores que devuelva `f` para cada valor del rango.

```
sum(f(x) for x in range(a, b, dn))
```